# Yacc expansion of optional clause using the same keyword as following clause

Tags: c++, programming-languages, language-design, yacc, bison

I'm developing a small DSL and having problems getting Yacc (Bison) to cleanly parse for the following symbols:

```
START (RETURN expression WHERE expression)* RETURN (expression)?
```

This is what I have so far, but I keep getting shift / reduce conflicts and I'm not sure how to fix them:

```
start: START conditional_returns returns |
       START returns;

conditional_returns: conditional_returns conditional_return | conditional_return;

conditional_return: RETURN expression WHERE expression;

returns: RETURN expression | RETURN;
```

I can see that the fact the RETURN keyword is reused in a different clause is causing problems, but I'd like to understand how to split this up correctly using this many rules. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By themselves, the above rules don't cause any problems; yacc/bison can handle them just fine with no shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflicts.  Where you might be getting into problems is if `start` is also a legal `expression`.  If that's the case, the language is ambiguous -- when you have a `start` within a `start`, a WHERE might be associated with either one.  For example, the input

```
START RETURN START RETURN expr WHERE expr RETURN expr
```

could be parsed as either

```
START RETURN ( START RETURN expr ) WHERE expr RETURN expr
```

or

```
START RETURN ( START RETURN expr WHERE expr RETURN expr )
```

depending on what is right for your DSL, you can change the grammar to enforce one meaning or the other, or to disallow nested `start` expressions if they don't make sense.